# Need Extension Suggestions for Multi-Restaurant Ordering Website

Tags: component, plugin, extensions

Hello Can anyone suggest me which extension should i use?  i want to create a Multi Restaurants food ordering website eg: https://eatoye.pk for Joomla!

Comment: I researched this quite some time ago (about 2yrs ago).  The closest solution I found was a directory extension called SobiPro which had a restaurant template for their directory engine, but without the functionality to place orders.  It's possible somebody may have extended SobiPro for that as it is widely used.  See https://demo.sobi.pro/restaurant-guide for an example and contact https://www.sigsiu.net (the extension developer) to see if they know of a solution that includes the ability to place orders.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla and Wordpress aren't a good starting point for that type of site as they don't really contain any of the functionality you need out-of-the-box.  Extensions (if they exist) would basically be a CMS on top of a CMS.

A Google shows some restaurant CMSs do exist - I have no idea if this is any good, but https://tastyigniter.com is the first one I found.

In terms of the example you gave, I'd expect a site that size to use bespoke code.  To build a site of that size, you need to think about scalability and not be trapped by the limitations of third party code.